# How can I add an item to a IEnumerable<(T item, int? number)>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

So, I have method:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T item, int? number)> DoTheThing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int? someNumber)
```

Basically I need return collection from parameters with added numbers in some cases.
I created empty collection to store data while forming end result trough `foreach`:

```
IEnumerable<(T item, int? number)> enumResult = Enumerable.Empty<(T item, int? number)>();
```

But I can't figure out how to add values to `enumResult`.
Only thing I can't change - method signature, so maybe I'm doing wrong thing entirly.

Comment: Hmm maybe I am missing something, but isn't this solved by just changing enumResult to List<(T item, int? number)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the interface is that you don't need to know anything about the source of the list, only that you can enumerate it. It could be that the method returns a list, computes the elements on the fly or reads them from the internet one at a time.

To add a value, you'll need to make sure that you work with a `List<T>`:

```
var enumResult = new List<(T item, int? number)>();
enumResult.Add(...);
```

Note that a `List` is also an `IEnumerable` so you can still use `enumResult` wherever the `IEnumerable` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
      public static IEnumerable<(T item, int? number)> DoTheThing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int? someNumber){
        foreach (T val in this){
          yield return val; 
        }
        if(someNumber.HasValue)
           yield return someNumber.Value;
      }
```